# What's the best way to break a div outside of a its set width parent container

Tags: css

I run into this issue a lot where I need the width of an inner container (like a wrapper with a set width of 960px) to span a width of 100%, and I'm unable to touch the html so it must all be done with css.

I know I can position: absolute; that guy to break him out of the wrapper... but is there another... better way?

Here is a JsFiddle link to help make it a little clearer:

http://jsfiddle.net/KRyF6/

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner-container"></div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->

#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    margin: auto;
}

/* here's the container that I want to be 100% */
#inner-container {
    width: 100%; /* :( */
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}
```

Edit:

Here is a jsFiddle with my absolute position version... what I'd like to know is if this can be done without absolute positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/KRyF6/3/

```
<div id="container2">
    <div id="inner-container2">
</div>

#container2 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#inner-container2 {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you setup a jsFiddle of the situation and then post the link here. It will help others help you. You will save everyone time.

Comment: Suggestion appreciated and post has been adjusted.

Comment: #inner-container IS 100%. so what do you mean? you want it to have a 100% over the hall page? maybe could you add a picture to what it should look like at the end, I don't really get it

Comment: sorry.. yes, the inner container should span the entire page... I'll try and provide a pic of what it should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is another way of doing this.

---

### Body -> Container -> child

Now this way as the title suggest is passing its width to the container and from the container to it's child. This way the child can get the total width of the body.

**Explanation**

The only problem you are facing here is that an static width will not keep the `<body>` width in mind(aka the viewport). So you have to use percent values for the width so it will be *based* on the `<body>`:

```
#container {
    /*width: 500px;*/
    width: 70%;
    height: 500px;
    background: gray;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Now the child knows that the width of its parent(`#container`) is 70% of the total body.

However a width of 100% will only get 70% of the `<body>` width. Instead you need 100% + the 30% of the 70%. And 30% of 70% is like 42%( 35% would be 50%).

Now we got the 100% of the `<body>`. Now you can let it look like it is outside the container width a negative margin. To center it you want it to be minus half of the 42%(=30% of the body) which you just calculated:

```
#inner-container {
    /*width: 100%; /* :( */
    width: 142%;
    margin-left: -21%;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRyF6/6/)

**However, is this easy to use?**

Well it is an answer to your question. It is possible without using `position: absolute`.

**Would position absolute be easier?**

Definitely:

```
#inner-container {
    width: 100%; /* :( */
    height: 100px;
    background: black;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Only two lines of code without any calculates :)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRyF6/7/)

Comment: This answers the question, so I have to click the green check mark.  If there were another checkmark for cleverness, this is more deserving of that... I'm going to study this for another 5 minutes :)

Comment: @ClasslessAndFree Hehe, thank you! It was a fun challenge, glad it helped :)

Comment: the only other thing this needs is an `overflow: hidden;` otherwise the x axis keeps scrolling, which could cause problems down the road, so the `position: absolute;` is what I'm going with for now... but I have to say, if you are able to come up with this solution on the spot, you must have been doing this for a while... I still don't fully get it, but it works perfectly.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to explain with a percentage of percentage ^^ But basically you have to see it this way: The `#inner-container` can not look higher then its parent (`#container`). Because the `#container` is 70% of the total width of the body (it doesn't matter how big your body is, it's always 70%). Now the child can have a width of 100%, which is based on its parent. Thus it takes the total width of its parent, which is 70% of the body. Then i calculate the extra spacing which the `#container` didn't have (the extra 30%).

Comment: But again it is Body -> container -> child and Body <- container <- child.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and say 'no' on this one. 
There's no way of making the inner div span the entire width of the page *without breaking it out of the document flow*, i.e. absolutely positioning it.

Comment: I think you are also correct.... I wonder if there is a better way to write the markup for something like this... but that's for a different thread... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done only with absolute position:

```
#inner-container {
    width: 100%; /* :( */
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRyF6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this can be done with calc() in conjunction with viewport units vw

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KRyF6/5/)** - Working in iE10+

```
#inner-container {
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(250px - 50vw);
}
```

Actually, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) (see example 14) - this *should work* (that is - in *all browsers*), but for now there's [a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158) where calc doesn't work with viewport units.

Alternatively you could do this:

```
#inner-container {
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    margin-right: calc(250px - 50vw);
    margin-left: calc(250px - 50vw);
}
```

-- this way - in IE it will look as required, and on other browsers it will look centered as you have it.
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KRyF6/8/)**

Comment: That does work... unfortunately I need to support those older browsers... like IE8.... But thanks for introducing me to calc and viewport units... I love learning the new stuff!  (fyi this also works in IE9)

Comment: Cool! never heard of these units before. Sad that `calc` is bugged in chrome with these viewport units :(